# Function pointer parameter without asterisk

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, function-declaration

I have seen this definition of a function that receives a function pointer as parameter:

```
double fin_diff(double f(double), double x, double h  = 0.01) {
  return (f(x+h)-f(x)) / h;
}
```

I am used to see this definition with an asterisk, i.e.:

```
double fin_diff(double (*f)(double), double x, double h  = 0.01);
```

Do you know why the first definition is also valid?

Comment: Functions and function pointers have same meaning when used as a function's parameter.

Comment: While you need to know about function pointers and such, in C++ you really shouldn't use them yourself if you can avoid it. If you intend to call the function directly, as in the example shown, use templates instead. Otherwise use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Using templates or `std::function` increases the flexibility by allowing you to pass any kind of callable object with the right signature, like a lambda, functor object, actual function pointer, etc.

Comment: The languages `c` and `c++` are two different languages.  Please choose one and remove the other `tag` as the answer is different depending on the language

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Standard says that these two functions are equivalent as function arguments are adjusted to be a pointer to function arguments:

> **16.1 Overloadable declarations [over.load]**
>   (3.3) Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are equivalent. That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type (11.3.5).

same in C:

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
>   8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to
>   function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

Comment: Which standard? C or C++?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I've added a quote from C standard as well. The first one is obviously from C++ because C does not have overloads

Answer (score 20):

Pointers to functions are peculiar. Given a function `void f();`, you can do

```
void (*fptr)() = f;
void (*fptr)() = &f;
void (*fptr)() = &&f;
void (*fptr)() = &&&f;
```

ad infinitum.

Similarly, when you call a function through a pointer to function you can do

```
fptr();
(*fptr)();
(**fptr)();
(***fptr)();
```

ad infinitum.

Everything collapses.

Comment: What's the motivation for this? It's not that this infinite chaining is otherwise impossible (consider a pointer whose referenced value contains its own address), but I don't see why all functions should behave this way.

Comment: @Alexander -- it's lost in the mists of time. <g>

Comment: @Alexander -- seriously, this comes from C, and has, as far as I know, always been the case. I don't know the reason for it.

Comment: According to James McNellis it's [C++'s best feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eX9gPithBo).

Comment: I think `&&f`, `&&&f`,... does *not* work. `**fptr` works though.

Comment: And... FYI who sees this, James McNellis' video @WesToleman mentioned above is just *joking*...

Answer (score 8):

If a function parameter is specified as a function declaration then the compiler itself implicitly adjusts the parameter as a function pointer.

It is similar to when a function name is passed as an argument of some other function as for example

```
fin_diff( func_name, 10.0 );
```

the compiler again implicitly converts the function designator to a pointer to the function.