# I have just started learning function pointers in C and and was trying to code a program but there seems to be a problem and I can't understand what?

Tags: c, function-pointers

So, I was trying to code a program which asks the user to input the points of a graph to calculate the euclidean distance and uses it as a radius to give the area of a circle. 
Here's my code:

```
/*You have to take four points(x1,y1,x2,y2) from the user and use it radius to find area of a circle. To find the distance between these points, you will use the Euclidean distance formula.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14

float euclideanDistance(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2)
{
    float ed = 0;
    ed = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
    return ed;
}
int areaOfCircle(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float(ed)(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2))
{
    return PI * (*ed)(x1, y1, x2, y2) * (*ed)(x1, y1, x2, y2);
//not sure if it's correct or not. No error squiggles.

}
int main()
{
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
    float (*fptr)(float, float, float, float);
    fptr = euclideanDistance;
    printf("Enter the four points x1,y1,x2,y2 to calculate the Euclidean Distance.\n");
    printf("x1:");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
    printf("y1:");
    scanf("%f", &y1);
    printf("x2:");
    scanf("%f", &x2);
    printf("y2:");
    scanf("%f", &y2);
    ;
    printf("The euclidean distance is %f", fptr(x1, x2, y1, y2));

    printf("The area of the circle which has the above mentioned Euclidean Distance as it's radius is: %f", areaOfCircle(x1, x2, y1, y1, fptr(x1, y1, x2, y2))); //error in this printf.

    return 0;
}
```

There are two problems over here.
I am not getting how to use the function euclideanDistance as a radius in areaOfCircle and second is how to implement it in my main function.
For the second problem In the VS Code it's showing me the error that.

> {"message": "argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "float (*)(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)""}

Please explain what I'm doing wrong and guide me.

Comment: `float(ed)(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)` That is not a function pointer. Compare it to how you have defined the function pointer in `main`. Also, it is common to define a typedef for function pointers to make it easier to use in multiple places: `typedef float (*ed_func)(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);` and then use as `ed_func fptr = euclideanDistance;`

Comment: @kaylum That does work as a function pointer, despite the missing `*`: see https://godbolt.org/z/sz6sjqK36 and [Function pointer parameter without asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57143586/7509065)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Interesting. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're basically double-calling `euclideanDistance`. In `main`, you do `areaOfCircle(x1, x2, y1, y1, fptr(x1, y1, x2, y2))`, and then in `areaOfCircle`, you do `(*ed)(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. To pass a function pointer, you just pass it like any other kind of pointer, rather than calling it with arguments. In other words, change `areaOfCircle(x1, x2, y1, y1, fptr(x1, y1, x2, y2))` to `areaOfCircle(x1, x2, y1, y1, fptr)`.

Comment: thanks everyone who helped me with this program. In addition to this problems you guys helped me with I also had to change the function areaOfCircle from int type to float. Special thanks to @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica to show me the answer. It really helped.